# Javascript add events to HTML LI Tags

Tags: javascript

In Below function i want to click on LI and alert its value inside it. I am using eventListener but function runs and gives undefined alert as the page loads

Please help

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

function displayText(){
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  x[i].onclick = displayText();
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the functions immediately.

- Assign the function as follow: `x[i].onclick = displayText;`
- The event param `e` contains the element in context: `e.target`

**Look at this code snippet with those fixes:**

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

function displayText(e) {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].onclick = displayText;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

See? your code now is showing the `alert`.

## Resource

- [GlobalEventHandlers.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

**UPDATE:**  As mentioned by [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) you can use `this`directly within your function `displayText` because you have the element's context.

**So, you can implement your function `displayText` as follow:**

```
function displayText() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I’m not convinced that switching from `this` to `e.target` is useful.

Comment: @James you're right, however, it's good to show this way as well.  I'm going to mention your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. what i understood when i just pass function as displayText to onclick event i am passing a function name as reference to that click event and when i write displayText() then i am simply invoking a function. Please reply is my understanding correct?